# Need help selecting frequency range for peaks search after FFT operation

Tags: python, range, fft

I am a little new to this (and programming). I am trying to write a script that will help me analyze a large .wav file. It will, in theory, run a fft on time segments, output data corresponding to power v. frequency, perform a peak power search on a range of frequencies and append that to another new array which I will use to build a histogram later.

The step I am stuck on is selecting a frequency range and having the screen print the maximum power for that frequency range (my attempts are after the plt.show() )
I want to be able to return a peak power for the range of frequencies 260-270Hz... any suggestions (I have made adjustments in that main block to return dbm v Hz already)?

```
for i in range(reads-1):
    if i > 0:
        break
    print 'working on set {:d} \n'.format(i) 
    waveData = wavFile.readframes(int(Windowsize))
    waveDataunpack = struct.unpack(formatstring,waveData)
    fftData = ((np.fft.rfft(waveDataunpack)/Windowsize))
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(Windowsize+1, float(1.0/rate))
    plt.plot(freqs[:16385],10*np.log10(np.abs(fftData)))
    plt.ylabel('power (dBm)')
    plt.xlabel('frequency (Hz)')
    plt.ylim((0,50))
    plt.xlim((0,500)) 
    #plt.show()

    pointy = fftData[freqs.index(260)]
    #print pointy
    #print(fftData.max)
    #print max(10*np.log10(np.abs(fftData)));
```

Comment: I don't know what the protocol is here, If you want me to upload the rest of the script to add context I can. I just didn't think it was necessary for understanding my question.

Comment: you probably want to do something like that (I am not sure about the spelling, try it out): `maxSpecInTheRange = np.max(fftData[freqs>260 and freqs<550])`  - that would only give you the maximum of the range (260 to 550) and not the maximum of the whole spectrum. You might also want to integrate this range instead of finding the peak - might be smoother. But essentially what you are trying to do is called spectrogram and there are tools for doing that (google for that)

Comment: or in your example you might want to do: `fftData[freqs.index(260):freqs.index(550)`

Comment: Hmm those attempts, in order, gave me errors:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my range problem with enumeration.

```
ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(windowed_freqs) if x >= 240 and x <= 285]

#now take the DB data only at the indicies where x is between the proper range.
value = fftData_inDB[ind]

#print freqs[ind]
maxval=-1000
maxind=0
for j in ind:
    if fftData_inDB[j] > maxval:
        maxval = fftData_inDB[j]
        maxind = j
print 'max power in range is {} dBm'.format(maxval)
print 'corresponding frequency is {} Hz'.format(freqs[maxind])
```